# Problems in migrating Struts 2.3 to 2.5

Tags: java, http, configuration, struts2, struts-action

I'm trying migrate from Struts 2.3 to 2.5.2 but I have two weird problems. They were good in 2.3 so maybe the problem is about Convention plugin.

Let's assume I have two actions:

```
mypackage.actions.LimitAction
mypackage.actions.user.UserAction
```

In 2.3 :

```
http://myurl/limit.action          -> OK
http://myurl/anything/limit.action -> There is no Action ... which is OK
http://myurl/user/user.action      -> OK
```

In 2.5:

```
http://myurl/anything/limit.action -> OK ... which should be There is no Action ...
```

And if I set in default action in struts.xml:

```xml
<default-action-ref name="other" />

<action name="other" class="mypackage.actions.OtherAction">
    <result />
</action>
```

Then

```
http://myurl/limit.action          -> went wrong and OtherAction is shown
```

It seems that if I have default action then every action in main package (mypackage.actions) is hidden by OtherAction but

```
http://myurl/anything/limit.action -> still works which is wrong too
```

Is it a bug in Struts 2.5.2?
How can set default action without making actions in main package wrong?
How can I fix not to access actions in main package with anyurl/*.action

Answer (score 1):

Both problems are fixed by setting `"/"` namespace in every action in the main package:

```
@Namespace("/")
```

When request url is

```
/anything/limit.action
```

and Struts can't find the action, it will look after LimitAction in the default `""` namespace.